# How to solve $1.1^x +1.5^x = 3.46$

Tags: calculus

I'm drawing a total blank as to how to solve this for x ...

$$
1.1^x + 1.5^x = 3.46
$$

I thought I could differentiate and substitute the first derivative back into the equation, but I must be rustier than I thought because I'm it's not working out correctly.

Incidentally, the answer is $x=2$.

Any thoughts on how to solve this type of equations would be very much appreciated.

Kindest regards,

Jack

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you already *see* that $x=2$ is *a* solution, then you only have to add to this observation that the function
$$x\ \mapsto\ (1.1)^x+(1.5)^x$$
is *strictly increasing*, so, in particular it is *one-to-one*, i.e. takes a value at most once, which proves that $x=2$ is the *only* solution.

Comment: Okay, but if you don't already know the answer, how do you solve it???

Comment: Unless you get lucky, you really need to use a numerical method to do this.

Comment: Ouch! I didn't realize this was not directly solvable. No wonder I was having so much trouble :-(

Comment: I think there might be a way with linear algebra if we're allowed to raise matrices to real powers (I'm not completely sure though).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Newton's Method to compute this in 2-3 steps after setting up the correct formula:

$$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac {1.1^x + 1.5^x-3.46}{0.0953102 \cdot 1.1^x + 0.405465 \cdot 1.5^x} $$

where $x_0 = 1$.

I don't believe there's an analytical way to solve for $x$ efficiently, unless you go crazy with a Taylor series representation of $f(x) = 1.1^x + 1.5^x$ centered at $x=0.$

Of course, you can always plug 'n' chug for small values..

Comment: How about expressing $1.5$ as $1.1^{log_{1.1}{1.5}}$ and then using Lambert W? It would not be so crazy and the result would be a closed formula.